# Easy way to solve integrals involving rational function

Tags: integration

> $$
> \int \frac{ 2x +8}{\left( x^2 +2x +3 \right) \sqrt{x^2 +2x +4}}\ dx
> $$

I started by completing the square and then substituting x+1=t but after that I am stuck.Can anybody help please.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1BIk.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What is that mysterious character next to the upper right parenthesis ? Eighree ?

Comment: Please don't let us assume about new users best interest. We may simply have no clue about that. **But** it is very good practice on typesetting to learn mathjax and it will also make other users *happier to help*. Which can be valuable for you. Here is a tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image of the attempt: How to solve:
$$
\int\frac{3}{(t^2+2)\sqrt{t^2+3}} \;dt
\tag{1}$$
Inside the square-root we see $t^2+3$ which is a sum of squares, $t^2 + (\sqrt{3})^2$.  (This is the reason for your substitution $x+1=t$ ... to get no $t$ term here, only $t^2$ and constant terms.) Therefore, I will try the substitution $t=\sqrt{3}\tan\theta$.  I choose that thinking of a right triangle with opposite side $t$, adjacent side $\sqrt{3}$, and hypotenuse $\sqrt{t^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}$.  Then $\theta$ is an angle of that triangle.  Draw a picture of that triangle to get
$$
\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}} = \tan\theta,\qquad dt = \sqrt{3}\sec^2\theta\;d\theta\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{t^2+3}} = \cos \theta\\
$$
then substitute into $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks sir by the way is there any other method to solve in a short way not from my attempt

Comment: Please tell sir is there any other method to solve not considering my attempt

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the so-called Euler substitution
$$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}=\pm x\sqrt{a}+t$$ so $$x=\frac{c-t^2}{\pm2t\sqrt{a}-b}$$

Comment: I tried it answer is not matching

Comment: Can you solve please or suggest any other method

Comment: @Calculuslover : It is impossible to respond to your work since you have not shown your work.  You should add your attempt to evaluate the integral to your Question.

Comment: Edited:added my attempt

Answer (score 0):

Put $x+1=t$ and your integral gets simplified to $$2\int\frac{t+3} {(t^2+2)\sqrt{t^2+3}} \, dt$$ which gets split as sum of two integrals $$2\int\frac{t}{(t^2+2)\sqrt{t^2+3}}\,dt+6\int\frac{dt}{(t^2+2)\sqrt{t^2+3}}$$ Put $1/\sqrt{t^2+3}=u$ in first integral and $t/\sqrt{t^2+3}=v$ in second integral and proceed further.